# Error "No se pudo cargar la información de la base de datos" al generar un reporte en Crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

estoy teniendo un problema al generar reportes con crystal reports en la maquina donde hago del deploy de la aplicación.
El error es el sisguiente:
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: Error en el archivo InformeResumenCuenta 6508_4848_{26BE9193-6C57-449B-B3D7-2CFCC4EC153F}.rpt:
No se pudo cargar la información de la base de datos. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error en el archivo InformeResumenCuenta 6508_4848_{26BE9193-6C57-449B-B3D7-2CFCC4EC153F}.rpt:
No se pudo cargar la información de la base de datos.

Info de la aplicación:

- Uso .NETFramework 4.0
- Base de datos Sql server
- En el App.config **si tengo** la siguiente línea: (vi varios post donde indican tener esta línea y aunque si la tengo arroja el mismo error)
  `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" /></startup>`
- Desde mi Pc no tengo problemas para generar el reporte
- Utilizo el siguiente código para cargar los datos al reporte:

```
    Entidades.DSEstadoCuenta tarjs_imprimir = Negocio.Detalle_Tarjeta.getInstancia().ImprimirSaldos(numero_clien);
    ReportDocument reporte_imp = new ReportDocument();
    reporte_imp.Load("c:\\InformeResumenCuenta.rpt");
    reporte_imp.SetDataSource(tarjs_imprimir);
    this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte_imp;
```

- En un momento me funciono sin problemas, pero desde que actualice el crystal reports en mi pc me dejo de funcionar en la pc donde instalo la aplicación.
- Ahora utilizo la versión 13.0.26.3348 tanto en mi PC como en la PC donde estoy instalando la aplicación donde falla. (32-bit)

Agradezco muchísimo cual pista que me puedan dar!
Saludos
Nicolás

Comment: Estoy exactamente con el mismo problema y los mismos datos,, solo que yo actualice a la version 13.0.30 pero el error es el mismo.

Comment: Yo estoy en la misma situacion y aun no logro encontrar la causa del error :(